# Dynamic focus on first input/text area is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to open my form and focus  automatically on first input or text area, and the `.focus()` function I used is working on Chrome and Safari(even in IE). But unfortunately it is not working in Firefox and IOS chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Check whether it is focused on first text area!");
  $("#form input:text").first().focus();
  //$(":input:first").focus();
  //setTimeout(function (){$("#form input:text, #formId textarea").first().focus(); }, 0);
  $('#do').on('click', function() {
    alert("Thanks!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="firstelement" value="myvalue" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="anotherelement" value="myvalue2" />
  <input type="submit" id="do" />
</form>
```

I have Tried setting timeout but it is also not working.

I have created a [jsfiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/zdoL42kt/3/) in this for chrome, the focus is happening (blue shade around the text area). but for Firefox it is not(dotted line around the area).

Is it a bug in Firefox? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: take a look to [-moz-user-focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus): see the note for textbox

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `autofocus` HTML5 attribute if you so desire.

I tested autofocus on IE11, Chrome and Firefox. Only does not seem to be working in a stack snippet. ( iframe shenanigans ? )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="firstelement" value="myvalue" autofocus>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="anotherelement" value="myvalue2">
    <input type="submit" id="do">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't use auto focus(btw it's still not working in firefox), I want to focus on whatever comes/ enabled first in form.(client specific). and In actual code i am opening the form in iframe.